# What's the difference between "For once" and "At once"

Tags: british-english

Please show me the meanings,when to use and can it be allowed to misuse these two ? (Also greetings from VietNam!)

Answer (score 2):

They are completely different. *For once* means *for this one time*. Typically it's used when something is an exception to the norm; it doesn't necessarily mean that the event being described is unique.

Say if I am habitually late to the office, but one day manage to make it in at 8 am on the dot. My colleague might remark:

> Well, Verbose, you're on time *for once*!

This doesn't mean I have never been on time before or will never be on time in future; it simply means that my being on time is a rare event, and can in some exaggerated sense be considered unique.

*At once* means *immediately*:

> Come here *at once*!
>   When I heard the good news, I called to congratulate her *at once*.

There is no overlap in meaning between the two phrases.

Comment: You've missed an opportunity to illustrate the two idioms with the same formulation: *Verbose, clean up your mess at once/for once!* But still worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @deadrat Or I could have brought you into the conversation with "Get rid of this dead rat at once!" 